# How to explicitly set checkbox unchecked

Tags: html, checkbox, unchecked

I have a xhtml page with transitional doctype having a checkbox that I want to be unchecked after loading. No JavaScript! In Firefox 3.5 (for instance, there may be other browsers) user can check input, than reload page and get input checked. How can I overcome this behaviour?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `autocomplete="off"` should work in your case I think.

Comment: JohnP you should Answer instead of commenting.

Comment: In firefox, it is also common that if a checkbox input does not have a name, it is checked by default.

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299811/why-does-the-checkbox-stay-checked-when-reloading-the-page

Comment: shasi: Thanks for that comment; saved me. Couldn't figure out why my logic was backwards in Firefox.

Answer (score 8):

Use

```
autocomplete="off"
```

Also have a look at [Why does the checkbox stay checked when reloading the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299811/why-does-the-checkbox-stay-checked-when-reloading-the-page)

Answer (score 6):

You can't do much to change a document's state with HTML alone. All you can do is set `checked="checked"` or not.

You need either JavaScript or a server side language to determine whether that attribute should be set or not.

Comment: JohnP made a comment that does for me best, but it should be mentioned that header "Cache-Control: no-cache" also helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, not without JavaScript. This is Firefox specific behaviour which would occur even if you *could* explicitly force an "unchecked" state (which you can't, because the absence of `checked` already means that.)

The only non-Javascript way that I know of is to rename the form element on server-side on every  request so FF has no chance of storing the value.

Answer (score 1):

To explicitly set the checkbox to unchecked, the following worked for me:
`<input type="checkbox" unchecked>`

Answer (score -2):

Try to put in your code this:

```
<p><label><input id="test" type="checkbox"></input>Test checkbox</label></p>
```

It will be unchecked when the page starts or refreshes.

Comment: tag input is a self closing tag, hence the `</input>` is illegal

Comment: According to [Mozilla's MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/checkbox#checked), Firefox persists checkbox status between page loads via autocomplete.