# How to disable/enable a button with a checkbox if checked

Tags: javascript, html

Please i need a script that can work with the HTML code bellow to disable/enable the button when a checkbox is checked or unchecked,

`<input type="submit" name="sendNewSms" class="inputButton" id="sendNewSms" value="    Send    " />`

please pals i don't mean the button to be disabled when checked, but rather the other way round.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

brbcoding have been able to help me with the appropriate coding i needed, here is it

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkme"/>
  <input type="submit" name="sendNewSms" class="inputButton" disabled="disabled" id="sendNewSms" value=" Send " />
```

**Javascript**

```
 var checker = document.getElementById('checkme');
 var sendbtn = document.getElementById('sendNewSms');
 // when unchecked or checked, run the function
 checker.onchange = function(){
if(this.checked){
    sendbtn.disabled = false;
} else {
    sendbtn.disabled = true;
}

}
```

Comment: it's disable and not enbaling

Answer (score 66):

You can use `onchange`event of the checkbox to enable/disable button based on `checked` value

```
<input type="submit" name="sendNewSms" class="inputButton" id="sendNewSms" value=" Send " />

<input type="checkbox"  onchange="document.getElementById('sendNewSms').disabled = !this.checked;" />
```

Comment: thanks, but i never mean the other way, the code above disabled the button when checked, but i want the button to be disabled and then enabled when the checkbox is checked

Comment: @Chidi updated the code. You simple needed to add `!` - `not` operator

Comment: this works way better than the other solutions provided

Comment: looks like one of those cases where inline javascript is the cleanest solution. Very nice!

Comment: i would add the "disabled" attribute to the button

Comment: This will not work correctly if, on clicking a button, you go to another page, and then go back. For example, in Chrome, the checkbox remains active, but the button is disabled. This answer solves this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17742818/9590536

Answer (score 23):

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkme"/><input type="submit" name="sendNewSms" class="inputButton" id="sendNewSms" value=" Send " />
```

**JS**

```
var checker = document.getElementById('checkme');
var sendbtn = document.getElementById('sendNewSms');
checker.onchange = function() {
  sendbtn.disabled = !!this.checked;
};
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/brbcoding/n9z5D/)**

Comment: Obviously just switch the `sendbtn.disabled = false` to `sendbtn.disabled = true` or vice versa as needed. If you want it disabled on first visit, you can just add disabled to the button to begin with.

Comment: Keep in mind, you'll need to check this serverside as well. All it takes is removing `disabled` from [this line](http://i.imgur.com/m6n4vUl.png) in devtools and the button is enabled again.

Comment: can we do the script inline with <input> tag?

Answer (score 21):

You will have to use javascript, or the JQuery framework to do that. her is an example using Jquery

```
   $('#toggle').click(function () {
        //check if checkbox is checked
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {

            $('#sendNewSms').removeAttr('disabled'); //enable input

        } else {
            $('#sendNewSms').attr('disabled', true); //disable input
        }
    });
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/T6hvz/

Answer (score 3):

Here is a clean way to disable and enable submit button:

```
<input type="submit" name="sendNewSms" class="inputButton" id="sendNewSms" value=" Send " />
<input type="checkbox" id="disableBtn" />

var submit = document.getElementById('sendNewSms'),
    checkbox = document.getElementById('disableBtn'),
    disableSubmit = function(e) {
        submit.disabled = this.checked
    };

checkbox.addEventListener('change', disableSubmit);
```

Here is a fiddle of it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/sYNj7/

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using jQuery as it will do all the heavy lifting for you. The code is fairly trivial.

```
$('input:checkbox').click(function () {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('#sendNewSms').click(function () {
      return false;
    });
  } else {
    $('#sendNewSms').unbind('click');
  }
});
```

The trick is to override the 'click' event and effectively disable it. You can also follow it up with some CSS magic to make it look "disabled". Here is the code in JavaScript in case you need it. It's not perfect but it gets the point across.

```
var clickEvent = function () {
  return false;
};
document.getElementById('#checkbox').onclick(function () {
  if (document.getElementById('#checkbox').checked) {
    document
      .getElementById('#sendNewSms')
      .onclick(clickEvent);
  } else {
    document
      .getElementById('#sendNewSms')
      .removeEventListener('click', clickEvent, false);
  }
});
```