# Check if checkbox is checked and disabling button not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am trying to disable a button when a checkbox is not checked and enable it again when it's checked.

So to test I added a console log inside the code, but there is no message in my console when I check the checkbox.

My code:

```
the_terms.click(function() {
            console.log('test');
        if (jQuery(this).is(":checked")) {
            jQuery("#checkoutbtn").removeAttr("disabled");
        } else {
            jQuery("#checkoutbtn").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
    });
```

Then the button and checkbox:

```
<button type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Place Order') ?>" class="button btn-checkout" id="checkoutbtn" onclick="review.save();" disabled="disabled"><span><?php echo $this->__('Place Order') ?></span></button>
<p><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="voorwaarden" style="display:inline;"/><b> Ik ga akkoord met de algemene voorwaarden</b></p>
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Youve not defined `the_terms` as far as i can tell!

Comment: Works fine -> https://jsfiddle.net/w6mdxpdx/

Comment: `jQuery(this).is(":checked")` is a **really** long-winded way to write `this.checked`. Just FWIW. Also note that `disabled` is properly manipulated with `prop`, which accepts a handy boolean, so that whole `if/else` could be replaced with: `$("#checkoutbtn").prop("disabled", !this.checked);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable/enable a button with a checkbox if checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18110865/how-to-disable-enable-a-button-with-a-checkbox-if-checked)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you've provided `the_terms` is never defined. You checkbox has an id of `voorwaarden` use it in a jquery id selector.

```js
jQuery('#voorwaarden').click(function() {
    console.log('test');
    if (jQuery(this).is(":checked")) {
        jQuery("#checkoutbtn").removeAttr("disabled");
    } else {
        jQuery("#checkoutbtn").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<button type="submit" class="button btn-checkout" id="checkoutbtn" onclick="review.save();" disabled="disabled"><span>Place Order</span></button>
<p><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="voorwaarden" style="display:inline;"/><b> Ik ga akkoord met de algemene voorwaarden</b></p>
```

As commented, you should probably use a `.change` handler not a `.click` and `if (jQuery(this).is(":checked"))` would be better written as `if(this.checked)`.

More appropriate code for your intention would be

```
jQuery('#voorwaarden').change(function() {
    jQuery("#checkoutbtn").prop('disabled', !this.checked)
});
```

And if you're dynamically adding the checkbox after page load use this

```
jQuery(document).on('change','#voorwaarden', function() {
    jQuery("#checkoutbtn").prop('disabled', !this.checked)
});
```

Comment: Use a `.change` function instea of `click` - mines well do `this.checked` as well.

Comment: @tymeJV the appropriate use of event handlers and properties are outside of the scope of this question. I do agree with you though.

Comment: I have to agree with @tymeJV "disable a button when a checkbox is not checked" does not imply click at all... it IS in the scope of the question to apply the disable when the checkbox gets checked, not when it gets clicked.

Comment: @Salketer there is little difference with a checkbox. a click implies a change. But once again, I agree with you both

Comment: For some reason a console log is never fired for me. Maybe i should mention I am using magento, not that I know why that would matter because I made a custom js script in the same file that works just fine. When I add a console log outside of the function it shows like normal.

Comment: @twan your element probably doesnt exists when you try to add the event handler. Try using `on` rather than `click` (or `change`). See updated answer.

Comment: @Jamiec without getting too picky, "a click implies a change" but a change can be triggered by a number of other events... I'm not trying to pick on you, trying to help everyone get/provide best answer possible :)

Comment: @Salketer so can a click (and that inits a change). What's your point?

Comment: @Jamiec using the keyboard to (un)check the box wouldn't enable/disable the button. I also don't think that clicking a label triggers a click on the linked element, but it does change the checked attribute...

Comment: None of these (change/click/on) work for me, I don't even see the console log. What could it be? I am using a .toggle in a script just below it that works fine. And when I add the console log out of the function, it shows right away.

Comment: @twan update your question with a [mcve] using the stacksnippet button to demonstrate the exact issue.

Comment: @Jamiec I just got it to work with your code! It appears the checkbox was added after the pageload Thanks!