# Enable a button if atleast one checkbox is checked using javascript

Tags: javascript, checkbox

How to enable the submit button when I check atleast 1 checkbox?

```js
$("input[name='vehicle']"), submitButt = $("input[name='Submit']");
var checkboxes = $("input[name='vehicle']"),
  submitButtList = $("#Submit");
checkboxes.click(function() {
  submitButt.attr("disabled", !checkboxes.is(":checked"));
  if (!checkboxes.is(":checked")) {
    submitButtList.addClass("disabled");
  } else {
    submitButtList.removeClass("disabled");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car"> I have a car<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" disabled>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18110865/how-to-disable-enable-a-button-with-a-checkbox-if-checked) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458531/how-do-i-disable-a-submit-button-when-checkbox-is-uncheck) may help.

Comment: You did not tagged jquery but your question is jquery

Comment: You are missing `name` attribute on button.

Comment: @divya Please **do not** update question based on suggestions in comment or any answer

Answer (score 4):

Here is a `JavaScript` solution, since you have tagged `Javascript` and not `Jquery`

```js
function callFunction() {
  var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
  var checkedOne = Array.prototype.slice.call(checkboxes).some(x => x.checked);

  document.querySelectorAll('input[type="submit"]')[0].disabled = true;
  if (checkedOne) {
    document.querySelectorAll('input[type="submit"]')[0].disabled = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" onchange="callFunction()" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" onchange="callFunction()" value="Car"> I have a car<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" disabled>
```

Jquery solution:

Check the length of checked checkboxes and use `prop` to disable or enable the button.

```js
$("input[name='vehicle']").on('change', function() {
  $("input[type='submit']").prop('disabled', !$("input[name='vehicle']:checked").length);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car"> I have a car<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" disabled>
```

Comment: this => function is not compatible with internet explorer

Comment: Also, since OP is already using jQuery, we can assume jQuery solution is acceptable. We can even edit question and tag it

Comment: I have mentioned and given a simple JavaScript solution instead of using JQuery. And that doesn't mean a down-vote.

Comment: Downvote is because you were missing explanation. Hence my 1st comment. Also, is there any issue with OP's code that needs fixing? If yes, please specify it.

Answer (score 3):

give the same id for the check boxes and write javascript codes on the on click event on the check boxes which enables/disables the button if any one is clicked.

by giving the same name enables only one of the two to be selected

Answer (score 1):

Try this might help you

```js
function myFunction() {

  if (document.getElementById('bike').checked || document.getElementById('car').checked) {
   
    document.getElementById("btn").disabled = false;
  } else {

    document.getElementById("btn").disabled = true;
  }

 



}
```

```html
<input id="bike" type="checkbox" onchange="myFunction()" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
<input id="car" type="checkbox" onchange="myFunction()" name="vehicle" value="Car"> I have a car<br>
<input type="submit" id="btn" value="Submit" disabled>
```

Answer (score 1):

add name to submit button.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car"> I have a car<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit" disabled>
```

Answer (score 0):

### 1. Suggestion to improve your code

You have to add the "name" attribute to your  in order to run your code as expected:

```js
$("input[name='vehicle']"), submitButt = $("input[name='Submit']");
var checkboxes = $("input[name='vehicle']"),
  submitButtList = $("#Submit");
checkboxes.click(function() {
  submitButt.attr("disabled", !checkboxes.is(":checked"));
  if (!checkboxes.is(":checked")) {
    submitButtList.addClass("disabled");
  } else {
    submitButtList.removeClass("disabled");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car"> I have a car<br>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" disabled>
```

### 2. Suggestion to improve Milan Chheda plain javascript code

If you want, you can also use [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1657932/milan-chheda) [First answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47449031/9620269) with plain javascript in a shorter form:

You can replace:

```js
  document.querySelectorAll('input[type="submit"]')[0].disabled = true;
  if (checkedOne) {
    document.querySelectorAll('input[type="submit"]')[0].disabled = false;
  }
```

with

```js
    document.querySelectorAll('input[type="submit"]')[0].disabled = !checkedOne;
```

```js
function callFunction() {
  var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
  var checkedOne = Array.prototype.slice.call(checkboxes).some(x => x.checked);

  document.querySelectorAll('input[type="submit"]')[0].disabled = !checkedOne;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" onchange="callFunction()" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" onchange="callFunction()" value="Car"> I have a car<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" disabled>
```