# disable button based on checkbox state in thymeleaf and springboot

Tags: html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Based on checkbox state i want to enable button if this checkbox is checked and vice versa using thymeleaf with springboot.
Here is what i tried :

```
        <div>
            <label>
            <input type="checkbox" th:value="${test}">
                actif
                </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button [disabled]="${test == false}"  type="submit">Envoyer</button>
        </div>
```

In my contoller :

```
        private boolean test = false;
        model.addAttribute("test", test);
```

Comment: If you want this enable/disable to happen dynamically without page refreshes, then you need to use JavaScript. Once your HTML is sent from Thymeleaf to the browser, then Thymeleaf can no longer do work.

Comment: thanks, i can modify this logic and display error message after submitting my form to avoid what you have said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Wim Deblauwe has mentioned, the only way to do that properly is to use JavaScript. For this case it's relatively simple. See [this answer for details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18111178/14004073)