# clear/reapply tablesorter filtering on pageload

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, tablesorter, reset

I am not strong with the javascript, and I can sometimes copy JQuery code and make it work.  Please be patient with me.

I am using the lastest build of tablesorter as of a couple days ago.

I have a page with a table, and a checkbox.  When the checkbox is checked, I am applying a filter to the 7th row that is the value of a dropdownbox.  It works perfectly.

When I post the page, the filter is lost, but the checkbox checked status is maintained, which is out of sync.  So I call the function that reads the checkbox status and sets the filter again, but it doesn't work.  It appears that table is not initialized, and so the filter doesn't actually get applied.  I have tried on the _LoadComplete in the CodeBehind and in a window.onload function.  Neither work.

So I tried both filterinit and filterend functions, and a simple filter_saveFilters : true.  This maintains the filtering perfectly, but when I go to another page and come back, the filter is maintained and the checkbox is in an unchecked state.  Again out of sync.

I see that there are 2 methods that can be used to reset the saved filters. $('table').trigger('filterReset');  $('table').trigger('filterResetSaved');  I can not seem to get them to work.

All of the problems are at the time of the page loading.  Simply, if the checkbox is checked, apply filter and keep it until the checkbox is changed or the page is loaded without postback.

Filter function that reads the checkbox and the dropdown box and sets the filter and the tablesorter inialization.

```
function filterTS() {
    if (document.getElementById("slideTwo").checked == true) {
        var e = document.getElementById("selUsers");
        var selectedText = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
        var filters = $('table').find('input.tablesorter-filter'),  col = 7, txt = selectedText, cur = filters.eq(col).val(), mult, i;
        }
        else {
            var filters = $('table').find('input.tablesorter-filter'), col = 7, txt = '', cur = filters.eq(col).val(), mult, i;
        }
        if (cur && txt !== "") {
            mult = cur.split('|');
            i = $.inArray(txt, mult);
            if (i < 0) {
                mult.push(txt);
            } else {
                mult.splice(i, 1);
            }
            txt = mult.join('|');
        }
        filters.eq(col).val(txt).trigger('search', false);
    }
    //Tablesorter Initialization
    $(window).ready(function () {
        $("#GridView1").tablesorter({
            theme: 'green',
            sortList: [[0, 1]],
            headerTemplate: '{content}{icon}',
            dateFormat: 'mmddyyyy',
            sortMultiSortKey: 'shiftKey',
            sortResetKey: 'ctrlKey',
            usNumberFormat: true,
            widgets: ['zebra', 'filter'],
            widgetOptions: {
                filter_ignoreCase: true,
            }
        });
        $('table')
            .bind('filterInit', function () {
                // check that storage ulility is loaded
                if ($.tablesorter.storage) {
                    // get saved filters
                    var f = $.tablesorter.storage(this, 'tablesorter-filters') || [];
                    $(this).trigger('search', [f]);
                }
            })
            .bind('filterEnd', function () {
                if ($.tablesorter.storage) {
                    // save current filters
                    var f = $(this).find('.tablesorter-filter').map(function () {
                    return $(this).val() || '';
                    }).get();
                    $.tablesorter.storage(this, 'tablesorter-filters', f);
                }
            });
        $("#slideTwo").on("click", filterTS);
        $("#slideOne").on("click", hidedates);
```

What am I doing wrong?  Why can't I set the filter from code on the page load?  Where the hell do I put:

```
$('table').trigger('filterReset');
$('table').trigger('filterResetSaved');
```

do I need to change 'table' to '#Gridview1'?
Nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('table').trigger('update');
});
```

Or this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('table').trigger('updateAll', [resort]);
});
```

Comment: Yeah, that isn't working.  I have 2 different scenarios, one without filter saving, but trying to set at load through fiterTS(), and one with filter saving, where I am trying to clear it at page load  if checkbox is not checked.  I tried a number of variations of this, but it simply isn't producing any results.

Answer (score 0):

First off the code that is set up for "filterInit" and "filterEnd" are essentially the same as setting the [`filter_saveFilters` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#widget-filter-savefilters) to `true`.

Using `$('table').trigger('filterResetSaved');` is the method needed to clear the stored filter values; but again, it only works if the `filter_saveFilters` option is `true`.

As for the checkbox, you can set the checkbox attribute `autocomplete="off"` ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/q/299811/145346)) to have the state clear on page refresh; but now with the `filter_saveFilters` option set to `true`, any filters set by checking `#slideTwo` will be set on page refresh because the filter values are saved.. maybe the value of that filter could be checked on tablesorter initialization, and if it matches the values for `#slideTwo`, you could set the checkbox state?

If you need help with that code, it would be easier if you provided a demo, or example. I set [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/856bzzeL/949/) up for you to modify.

```
$(function() {
  $("#GridView1").tablesorter({
    theme: 'green',
    sortList: [[0, 1]],
    headerTemplate: '{content}{icon}',
    // dateFormat: 'mmddyyyy',
    // sortMultiSortKey: 'shiftKey',
    // sortResetKey: 'ctrlKey',
    // usNumberFormat: true,
    widgets: ['zebra', 'filter'],
    widgetOptions: {
      // filter_ignoreCase: true,
      filter_saveFilters: true
    },
    initialize: function(table) {
      var c = table.config,
        $s2 = $('#slideTwo'),
        // c.$filters points to the TD, not the input
        $filter = c.$filters.eq(3).find('.tablesorter-filter'),
        val = $filter.val();
      $s2.prop('checked', val === 'something');
    }
  });
});
```

* Note: the options that are commented out are already set to their default value.

Comment: Please note, my JQuery is very weak.  I think that the initialize function you have here does the following:  (1) grab the table config that we are going to modify (2) find the filter for the third tow (3) grab the value of that filter and put it in val (4) set checked if val = 'something'.  Is that correct?

Comment: A couple points that are making me nuts: (1) where does the code to remove the saved filters go (when filter_saveFilters = true) to clear them and have the tablesorter initialize with no filtering?  I can not seem to make it work.  No matter where I put those code lines, the table loads filtered.

Comment: (2) Is there a way to use the filterTS() function above to set the filters when the page loads?  It seems that I can not use the function as the page loads to set the filters.  They never get applied.  If I don't save the filters, but can use the javascript function to set the filters, I would be golden.

Comment: (3) is there a way with jfiddle to simulate the postback?  It is during the load process of the page that I am having difficulties modifying the filter settings.

Comment: You're understanding is mostly correct... `.eq(3)` actually targets the fourth column - it's a zero-based index (i.e. counting starts from zero). (1) If you look at the docs for the `filter_saveFilter` setting, you'll see this code: `$.tablesorter.storage( $('table'), 'tablesorter-filters', '' );` add it *before* initializing tablesorter to clear the filter. (2) The `TS()` function would work on page load because it only sets the filter, not the checkbox. (3) I don't think JSFiddle can do postbacks.

Comment: If you need more help, please feel free to open a chat room here, or contact me using one of [these methods](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter#questions) since I only check Stackoverflow a few times during the day.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense now.  It sure didn't earlier.  Better go comfort the dogs who probably think all the swearing was at them.

Answer (score 0):

So I made the whole operation easier by adding the data-value to the header of the table if the checkbox is checked like so in code behind page loadcomplete....

```
If Me.slideTwo.Checked=True Then GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells(10).Attributes.Add("data-value",selUsers.SelectedItem.Text)
```

and presto changeo it worked a treat.  I still do not know why calling the javascript function after the table sorter initialization is complete does not actually work.  It sets the text into the filter field, but it does not apply it.  The javascript works great once the page is loaded though.