# HTML checkboxes keep checked after refresh

Tags: html, checkbox

I have a couple of check boxes in my markup.. For example:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="someCheckbox"/>
```

If I refresh the page with `Ctrl+Shift+R` everything is OK - the page renders unchecked check boxes, however if some of them were checked and I refresh with `F5` they stay in their previous state.

Setting the `checked` attribute doesn't work since having the attribute is enough to make it checked, the value is more or less irrelevant..

How can I force them to be unchecked **on page load**, please?

Comment: A cursory search turned up this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299811/why-does-the-checkbox-stay-checked-when-reloading-the-page

Comment: That sounds like a feature of your browser, keeping form values in place in case of an accidental reload. Is this really something you absolutely need to override?

Comment: @Pekka웃 yes, otherwise I wouldn't have done it.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I've found a solution which uses only HTML. If you add the `autocomplete="off"` attribute to the element it won't set the previous state after refresh..

```
<input type="checkbox" id="foo" autocomplete="off"/>
```

Comment: I did but it is now working for me, means when refresh it goes?rows.push('<tr><td><input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" class="chkbox" name="chkbox" value="'+value.site+':'+value.client+'"></td><td>' + id + '</td><td>' + value.machine
        + '</td><td>' + value.state + '</td><td>'
        + value.date_processed + '</td><td><button type="button" onclick="resetSite(\''+ value.site+'\',\''+value.client+'\')">Reset</td></tr>');
     });

Comment: Helpful when your goal is to untick the checkbox upon page reloading or by clicking the back button

Comment: This just saved my day. Every day we learn and I learned this important thing. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You could set them back with javascript

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
for (var inp of elements) {
    if (inp.type === "checkbox")
        inp.checked = false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In hTML there is only checked attribute which force the checkbox to retain checked.
and by default the check boxes are unchecked.If you want to force unchecked after load then don't use.
**One Important thing** some time it also depend on browser.
**for more detail refer** http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp