# Chrome Safari ignores no-store cache-control directive

Tags: google-chrome, safari, bfcache

I have a page with a checkbox and a link to page A.

I click on the checkbox,
I click on the link, 
go to page A,
click browser back button,
come back

I still see the checkbox checked, it's not clearing up.

I have used proper cache-control headers as below.

```
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-store, no-cache
Expires: 0
```

Also, tried this:

```
document.body.onunload = function(){};
    document.body.onpageshow = function(evt) {
        if (evt.persisted) {
        document.body.style.display = "none";
        location.reload();
        }
    };
```

Nothing works in chrome and safari (desktop)

Works well on IE, Firefox, mobile chrome and safari.

Please help.

Comment: The persistent cache is probably not used. However, the in-RAM cache may still be active as the page wasn't evicted from memory during the navigation process.

Comment: i need to refresh the page. what should i do to force it? also in network tab, the DOCUMENT is not fetched from cache, i can verify that. But the form is not cleared.

Comment: for safari, adding below solved the problem:
<iframe style="height:0px;width:0px;visibility:hidden" src="about:blank">
    this frame prevents back forward cache
  </iframe>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be the same problem as [Why does the checkbox stay checked when reloading the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299811/why-does-the-checkbox-stay-checked-when-reloading-the-page)

What worked for me was to add `autocomplete="off"` into the form element on the page.