# Hamburger button transit to X button, but won't return as hamburger button when refreshed

Tags: html, css, button, hamburger-menu

Why when a person clicked on the hamburger button that transit to X button and decided to refresh and the X button remains?  How do you get the hamburger button to appear again after refreshing the site?

Here is the link to my website: http://dannysaavedra.com/photobeta

Here is the code for my hamburger button and X button in CSS.

This only occur in Firefox browser.

```
/*Begin Hamburger Menu*/
#menu {
  position: fixed;
  top:17px;
  right: 20px;
  height: 28px;
  width: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 7;
}

.nav-trigger {
  cursor: pointer;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
  position: fixed;
}

label {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#menuButton,
#menuButton:before,
#menuButton:after {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: fixed;
  top: 30px;
  right: 20px;
  z-index: 2;
  border-radius: 1px;
  height: 5px;
  width: 35px;
  background-color: white;
  content: '';
}

.nav-trigger:checked + #menuButton:before,
.nav-trigger:checked + #menuButton:after {
  top: 30px;
  right:20px;
  background-color: red;
}

#menuButton:before {
  top: 20px;
}

#menuButton:after {
  top: 40px;
}

.nav-trigger:checked + #menuButton:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.nav-trigger:checked + #menuButton {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.nav-trigger:checked + #menuButton:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.nav-trigger + #menuButton:before,
.nav-trigger + #menuButton:after {
  transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
}

.nav-trigger:checked + #menuButton:before,
.nav-trigger:checked + #menuButton:after {
  transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
}

.nav-trigger + #menuButton,
.site-wrap {
  transition: left 0.2s;
}

.nav-trigger + #menuButton {
  right: 20px;
  transition: right 0.2s;
  transition: all 10ms ease-in-out;
}

.nav-trigger:checked ~ .site-wrap {
  left: -300px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transition: left 0.2s;
}
```

Comment: Works for me without problems

Comment: Did you click the hamburger button once then click the refresh button?

Comment: Yep. I'm on Google Chrome by the way. Maybe it's the browsers cache? Ctrl+F5 might just work.

Comment: Oh ok, I use Firefox. Can you confirm this if you are running Firefox browser?

Comment: Oh yea it breaks in Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: 
It seems the :checked is not resetting in Firefox. I found a similar topic, which suggests adding `autocomplete="off"` to the given element. Find the topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299811/why-does-the-checkbox-stay-checked-when-reloading-the-page).

OLD:
Try adding -webkit-transition to all your transitions, like so:

```
-webkit-transition: someTransition;
transition: someTransition;
```

The same is true for transform.

Comment: Added webkit and it didn't work. Also, I decided to add moz, however no luck.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works!  I never thought Firefox had an aggressive cache-control.

Comment: Glad I could help :)