# Is it possible for a page ui to remain unchanged even after reloading the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to test some pages which have checkboxes in a form. Is it a good idea to include a test case which simply checks if all checkboxes are unchecked upon page reload ?

In other words, I am asking if its possible that checked checkboxes do not become unchecked even after reloading the page or by going to another page in that website & then returning to the page ?

Is this always caused by the browser and maybe poor programming/design ?

What i tried:
[Why does the checkbox stay checked when reloading the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299811/why-does-the-checkbox-stay-checked-when-reloading-the-page)

Comment: Yes this is possible if the browser has `autocomplete` enabled. You can disable it on your `form` if you set `autocomplete="off"`. This will force the controls to always load from the initial state set in your HTML code.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - It seems that the issue is only caused due to browser quirks or browser settings. Could bad programming/design cause it too ?

Comment: Yes - if the browser is in quirks mode then your HTML needs to be fixed.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Are you sure browser always acts correctly with this option? I usually have problems with login forms that does not looks for `autocomplete="off"`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - By browser quirks, i meant browser specific problems and not browser quirks mode.

Comment: It won't work in <IE11 if that's what you mean: http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-autocomplete-onoff. However you should never 'rely' on the page to be in a specific state. Sure, there's a lot of questions and answers mentioning caching etc, but all it boils down to is that fact that you should always work with the page as it is, and make sure your code is robust enough to handle it.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - So every form with checkboxes must have a test to check for unchecking upon page reload ?

Comment: No, the code should be able to handle having some checkboxes enabled on page load

Answer (score 0):

Its all dependent on browser caching. Each reload gives you that static page but due to page cache the checkbox remains checked. If you want them unchecked on each page reload, then either perform hard reloading Ctrl + Shift + R or set a control header : Cache-Control: no-store