# Force browser to render again when pressing F5

Tags: html, http

I have a page with a checkbox. If I select the checkbox, and press `F5` on Firefox 66, the page is refreshed, but the checkbox is still selected.

Request headers:

```
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Fedora; Linux x86_64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Response headers:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Thu, 16 May 2019 06:22:42 +0000
Date: Thu, 16 May 2019 06:22:42 GMT
Host: localhost:8080
```

Forcing the refresh with `Ctrl` + `F5` works as expected. The headers are exactly the same (except dates) for both F5 and Ctrl+F5. Are my headers wrong in any way or there is another mechanism that makes this happen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does the checkbox stay checked when reloading the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299811/why-does-the-checkbox-stay-checked-when-reloading-the-page)

Comment: CTRL + SHIFT + F5 ?